# Creating Fish tibble using %>%

Tags: r, r-markdown

I created a tibble named `fish`. Using the %>% operator, then created an object called a result that should take `fish` to then group entries by the species of fish and then compute the mean eye size of each species, but it is not coming out how it should. What am I doing wrong?

```
set.seed(23)
fish = tibble(
    species=c(rep("toadfish", 333), rep("frogfish",333), rep("batfish", 334)),
     body_size=rnorm(1000),
     eye_size=abs(0.022*rnorm(1000)/body_size),
     brain_volume=body_size^2*eye_size/.6
    )
 
result <- fish %>% mean(fish$eye_size)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create `result` and can do it in one step with piping.

```
fish %>% 
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(eye_size), .groups = "drop")
```

Edited to include @LMc's tip.

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can use the `aggregate` function:

```
with(fish, aggregate(eye_size, list(species), mean))
```